# Font Size Changes when WPF app runs

Tags: wpf

i have a problem. i am creating an application in WPF with 6-7 pages and main window.
i have set the application font size globally in the WPF app.xaml to 16
CODE:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"  Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="550"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="700"/>
</Style>
```

and while in design it looking good and changes in this font size is also reflecting in the app.
but when i run the app it is changing to other font size like 10 or 12 i think, it is becoming too small to see.
i have checked and removed any local font size definitions but still it is not working.

Using Snoop i checked.
The font size remains same till the frame of the main windows.
but when the page is loaded in the frame then, in that frame there is a Border(whcich i didn't add or can see) will change it to 11 size.
how to change a control which i  have not created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in app.cs  of your project

```
     public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ///add these lines
        FrameworkElement.StyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Page), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
        {
            DefaultValue = FindResource(typeof(Page))
        });

        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }
```